# Keep right click context menu on the screen

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, contextmenu

I have created an typescript component for my Context Menu and everything is working great except when the Context menu is activated near the edge of the screen it will go past the edge of the screen and some items will be inaccessible.

This is the HTML structure of my Context Menu

```
<div id="contextMenu">
  <div
    class="menu-link"
    *ngFor="let menuItem of contextMenuItems; index as i"
    (click)="onContextMenuClick($event, menuItem.menuEvent)">
    <div *ngIf="menuItem.menuText !== 'divider'">{{ menuItem.menuText }}</div>
    <hr *ngIf="menuItem.menuText == 'divider'" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The menu items are dynamically added based on the "context"

right click activates this code

```
displayContextMenu(event) {
this.myContextMenuService.buildMenu();
this.rightClickMenuPositionX = event.clientX;
this.rightClickMenuPositionY = event.clientY;
}
```

I've tried several CSS things but nothing has kept the entire menu on the screen no matter where you activate it from.

Comment: How are you activating/moving the menu?

Comment: You should use [angular's CDK library](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview), it already handles this kind of issues.

Comment: I don't want to use a library that will potentially get abandoned and not work with Angular updates in the future (been there done that)...the menu is activated through right click and displayed with the upper left corner on the screen coordinates.

Comment: Hi, the @angular/cdk will not be abandoned since it's part of the @angular/material toolkit. I wouldn't worry about that. [Here's an example](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/libs%2Fmintplayer-ng-bootstrap%2Fcontext-menu%2Fsrc) context menu. [Here's how to use it](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/apps%2Fng-bootstrap-demo%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Foverlay%2Fcontext-menu). [Here's a demo](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/overlays/context-menu) The benefits of @angular/cdk are simply too huge eg. `FlexibleConnectedTo`

Answer (score 1):

```
displayContextMenu(event) {
  this.myContextMenuService.buildMenu();
  // get your contextMenu width and height
  const contextMenu = document.getElementById('contextMenu');
  const contextMenuWidth = contextMenu.offsetWidth;
  const contextMenuHeight = contextMenu.offsetHeight;

  const xPos = event.clientX + contextMenuWidth > window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth - contextMenuWidth : event.clientX;
  const yPos = event.clientY + contextMenuHeight > window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight - contextMenuHeight : event.clientY;

  this.rightClickMenuPositionX = xPos;
  this.rightClickMenuPositionY = yPos;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why make this more difficult than it already is? Use [Angular's Cdk](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview), it takes care of this out of the box. Non need to re-invent the wheel

Answer (score -1):

Taking too long to get an answer from the community.
This is how I've decided to solve this problem...hopefully it will help someone else.

The below is triggered by a [ngStyle] call on the "contextMenu"
[ngStyle]="getYourClickMenuStyle()"

```
const rightClickMenuPositionX = event.clientX;
const rightClickMenuPositionY = event.clientY;
const cMenu = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('contextMenu');
const menuWidth = cMenu.offsetWidth + 30;
const menuHeight = cMenu.offsetHeight + 30;
const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
let menuStyleLeft = '';
let menuStyleTop = '';

if((windowWidth - rightClickMenuPositionX)<menuWidth){
menuStyleLeft = (windowWidth - menuWidth).toString() + "px";
} else {
  menuStyleLeft = rightClickMenuPositionX.toString() + "px";
}
if ( (windowHeight - rightClickMenuPositionY) < menuHeight ) {
  menuStyleTop = (windowHeight - menuHeight).toString() + "px";
} else {
  menuStyleTop = rightClickMenuPositionY.toString() + "px";
}
if(menuStyleLeft !== ''){
  return {
    position: 'fixed',
    left: menuStyleLeft,
    top: menuStyleTop
  }
}
```

Comment: lol... "taking too long" smh